# Inserting Scraped Results Into SQL Server

Tags: c#, html, sql-server

any ideas why I am getting "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll" when I try to insert the results of sccraping into SQL SERVER?

This is the code I am using:

```
public void scrape(string URL)
{
    using (SqlConnection opencon = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING"))
    {
        string saveStaff = "INSERT into Principale ((Name) VALUES (@Name)";
        opencon.Open();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string html = streamreader.ReadToEnd();

        HtmlDocument page = new HtmlDocument();
        page.LoadHtml(html);
        var document = page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='b_Namesummary']");

        foreach (var nodo in document)
        {

            String nome = nodo.SelectSingleNode("./h3[1]/a[1]").InnerText;
            SqlCommand querySaveStaff = new SqlCommand(saveStaff);
            querySaveStaff.Connection = opencon;
            querySaveStaff.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NChar, 30).Value = nome;
            querySaveStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(nome);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look carefully at the exception, you should have an InnerException that tells better what is wrong in your call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the sql exception, apart from the obvious syntax error in missing the closing parenthesis, (a typo?) comes from the fact that you declare a parameter named `@AlbergoName` but in the sql text you use the `@name` placeholder instead

Change to:

```
string saveStaff = "INSERT into Principale (Name) VALUES (@AlbergoName)";
```

By the way, you don't need to create an SqlCommand inside the loop, just create it outside and update its parameter value

```
SqlCommand querySaveStaff = new SqlCommand(saveStaff);
querySaveStaff.Connection = opencon;
querySaveStaff.Parameters.Add("@AlbergoName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
foreach (var nodo in document)
{
    string nome = nodo.SelectSingleNode("./h3[1]/a[1]").InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine(nome);

    querySaveStaff.Parameters["@AlbergoName"].Value = nome;
    querySaveStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Notice also that I have changed your parameter type to be NVARCHAR instead of NCHAR. NChar is a fixed length type, so if you declare NChar 30 you pass 30 characters whatever the length of your variable nome. I suggest to use NVARCHAR for the parameter type and set the size to the same size of your column Name....

Comment: I have edited the code above (sorry I was trying various solutions and posted a messy code) with the corrections you suggested.
I am still getting the error of truncating data.
Thanks for all your fast replies!

Comment: Well, now the problem is the length of data passed to your Name field. You declare the parameter to be 30 chars, but what is the length of the field in the datatable? Use an NVARCHAR parameter and be sure that it is not greater than the column

Comment: Don't forget, if the field is defined as `nvarchar` in SQL Server, then the length SQL Server reports for the field size is double the actual size; so, if SQL Server says the length is 30, then you can only insert 15 characters into the field.

Comment: @MetroSmurf are you sure about this. It doens't seems to be as you say

Comment: Thanks! It works! Sorry I am quite new to Sql! Thanks for all the replies, really!

Comment: @Steve; here's a SqlFiddle that demonstrates this behavior: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/622ce/1 - this happens due to an nvarcharfield using 2 bytes instead of 1 for storage to account for unicode.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
 "INSERT into Principale (Name VALUES (@Name)";
```

should be

```
 "INSERT into Principale (Name) VALUES (@Name)";
```

Also you do not need to explicitly close the connection when you have used `using` to open a connection.

The connection will be closed automatically when the using block goes out of scope. (A very good reason to use `using` over `Try, catch, finnaly`)

```
    opencon.Close();   // not needed
```

Comment: What's about `querySaveStaff.Parameters.Add("@AlbergoName", SqlDbType.NChar, 30).` and `String nome = nodo.SelectSingleNode("./h3[1]/a[1]").InnerText;`

Comment: Woa, superfast reply!! Fixed it but still getting the error, it says string or binary data could be truncated. The problem might be in the Foreach part of the code...
Thanks for the Close() tip, I didn't know it could be omitted!